# Difference between 芽生える{めばえる}・芽{め}が出る{でる}／芽{め}を出す{だす}

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, usage, nuances

I encountered the following multiple-choice question in an unofficial JLPT N3 vocabulary practice test:

> 先週、スイカの種を植えたばかりなのに、今朝見たら、もう芽が（　　　）いた。
>
> １　なって　　２　出て　　３　散って　　４　生えて

I chose 「４　生えて」, but the answer given is 「２　出て」.

I looked up example sentences on the weblio 英和辞典. 「[芽{め}が出る{でる}](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E8%8A%BD%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B)」 and 「[芽{め}を出す{だす}](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E8%8A%BD%E3%82%92%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99)」 both return many results, whereas 「× [芽{め}が生える{はえる}](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E8%8A%BD%E3%81%8C%E7%94%9F%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B)」 did not appear at all.  However, there is a word 「[芽生える{めばえる}](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E8%8A%BD%E7%94%9F%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B)」.

- What are the differences and nuances between 芽{め}が出る{でる}, 芽{め}を出す{だす}, and 芽生える{めばえる}?  Do they all mean "to germinate, to bud"?  (I cannot sense much of a transitive/intransitive distinction here.)
- It appears that × 芽{め}が生える{はえる} is not valid.  Is there a reason why 芽生える{めばえる} is a valid word, whereas × 芽{め}が生える{はえる} is not used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

芽が生える is acceptable, but just much less common than 芽が出る. [Shonagon](https://clrd.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/) returns 6 results for the former, 186 for the latter. So, 2 is the best choice, but 4 is not wrong.

For the differences:

- When speaking of plants or trees, all three mean mostly the same. 芽生える sounds somewhat literary.
- In terms of syntax, 芽を出す or 芽生える works like an intransitive verb (as a whole) while 芽が出る by itself is a sentence. Roughly 植物**が**芽を出す/芽生える = 植物**の**芽が出る.

The biggest difference is their collocations/metaphorical meaning.

- [芽が出る](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%8A%BD%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B/) can be used in the sense that some chances open up:  幸運が巡ってきて、成功の糸口が開ける。目が出る。「長い下積みを経てやっと―◦出る」
- [芽生える](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%8A%BD%E7%94%9F%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B/#jn-217822) can mean *(friendship, love, etc.) to start growing*: 物事が起こりはじめる。きざす。「愛情が―・える」

芽を出す is usually used literally for plants.

Comment: Clear and comprehensive answer!  I will leave a bit of time before accepting the answer.  Side note: my first encounter with the word 芽生える was in the lyrics of the opening theme of Death Note: 愛した故に芽生えた悪の花, which illustrates both its literal and figurative meanings nicely.